# Entropic uncertainty relations with measurements and memory

Tags: information-theory, entropy

In entropic uncertainty relations involving measurements and memory, one has a quantum state $\rho_{AB}$. Alice holds register $A$ and performs one of two measurements denoted by observables $R$ and $S$. One then formulates entropic inequalities such as

$$H(R|B) +H(S|B) \geq \log\frac{1}{c} + H(A|B)$$

for a constant $c$ that depends on the measurements. If $R$ consisted of the projectors $\{\vert\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i\vert\}$, then the state $\rho_{RB}$ would be given by

$$\sum_i (\vert\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i\vert\otimes I_B)\rho_{AB}(\vert\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i\vert\otimes I_B)$$

In a lecture, I came across the claim that for a pure state $\rho_{ABE}$

$$H(RB) = H(RE)$$

Why is this true?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've already answered this before.

Comment: @Rammus thanks! I trawled through your answers on the site a bit and found it here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/18437/prove-that-for-a-pure-tripartite-state-rho-abe-hrb-hre?rq=1. Have marked it as a duplicate now